# Averaging part of an array powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, average

Hi I am trying to return the average for part of an array, when the array is set out like

```
$multi = New-Object 'object[,]' $nucount,($readings + 2 )
and contains "1,4,2,6,3,4,5,nameofitem, cost of item"
```

I want to get an average for the first 7 elements which I know will always be the first 7 and always be a number. In the case above the number of elements containing a number will be held in a variable called $readings. So the sum I want to do is add up the elements in the array up to the $readings value. and then device by $readings.

I know of ways like this for the whole array

```
$Avg = ($array | Measure-Object -Average);
$Avg.Average;
```

or simple looping through and calculating the average buy adding and deviding.

But is there any short hand way to do this. I was going to used the ... operator

$multi[2,0..$readings] but i get an error of

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".

Any help with this would be great if it can provide a short code to replace the

```
for (x=1 ; $x -eq $readings ; $X++) 
{
$sum = $sum + $multi[2,$x]
{
$avg= $sum/$readings
```

Comment: It seem that you create two dimensional array, but try to use it as one dimensional.

Comment: sorry that was a miss type, it would be $multi[2,0..$readings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it works like this:

```
0..$readings | % { $sum += $multi[$_] }
```

or if not:

```
0..[int]$readings | % { $sum += $multi[$_] }
```

and first you have to initate $sum

```
$sum = 0
0..$readings | % { $sum += $multi[$_] }
$avg = $sum/$readings
```

here is another eample of what will work:

```
$arr = 1..50
$readings = 15
$arr[2..$readings]
```

regards Eldo.Ob

Comment: $multi[2,0..$readings] won't work, cause of the optimistic behavior of Powershell. because of the ',' powershell makes an array out of it.
$foo = 2,0  is an array with the values 2 and 0 - same as $foo = @(2,0)

Comment: (0..($readings-1) | % { $sum += $multi[$counterID,$_] }) seems to work perfectly :) Thank You

Answer (score 6):

You are going right way:

```
$readings=7
$array=1,4,2,6,3,4,5,"nameofitem", "cost of item"
$Avg = ($array[0..($readings - 1)] | Measure-Object -Average);
$Avg.Average;
```

Note that arrays are zero based…

Answer (score 2):

As you have indicated in your comment that array is 1-dimentional indeed, solution is straightforward:

```
$multi | select -First 7 | Measure-Object -Average
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$avg = (0..7 |% { $multi[2,$_] } | Measure-Object -Average)
```